# Find a sequence with an interesting property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was reading an Elon Lages Lima's book ("Curso de Análise", IMPA) and there is an interesting question. Find a function $f$ from $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb N$, the preimage set $f^{-1}(\{n\})$ is infinite. I don´t have any idea how to construct that.

Comment: Do you mean $f^{-1}\left(\{n\}\right)$?

Comment: @GitGud these two are the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I´m goint to edit that. Thank you.

Comment: @xyzzyz No. Only maybe to an analyst.

Comment: I hated this book every time I used it in a course. For research it is great anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sequence 
$$0,0,1,\color{green}{0,1,2},\color{red}{0,1,2,3},0,1,2,3,4, 0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$$

Comment: Quite clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(n) = k$ if $n = 2^k \cdot (2l -1)$ for natural numbers $k, l$ -- in other words, if $2^k$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $n$. Then $f^{-1}(k) = \{2^k \cdot 1, 2^k \cdot 3, 2^k \cdot 5, 2^k \cdot 7\ldots \}$.

Comment: Some natural number.

Comment: Great idea!!! Thak you

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

1. {x<sub>1</sub>: x<sub>1</sub> is prime OR 1}$\to 1$.
2. {x<sub>2</sub>: $x_2=2\cdot p$, for prime p>2}$\to 2$.
3. {x<sub>3</sub>: $x_3=3\cdot p$, for prime p>3}$\to 3$.
4. {x<sub>4</sub>: $x_4=4\cdot p$, for prime p>4}$\to 4$ 
   etc.

Sorry, I was a little sloppy.

Comment: This does not work, because for instance $6 = 2 \cdot 3$ is both a double of a prime and a triple of a prime. What does your function map 6 to?